# Should Camellias bloom in the northern hemisphere in early October?

Tags: shrubs, flowering, fall-gardening, camellia

I had a [*Camellia japonica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_japonica) 'Sweet Sensations' open two blooms on Oct 7, and a [*C. sasanqua*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_sasanqua) 'Setsugekka' open two on Oct 10, with many more blooms to come. The temperatures here in Texas are still reaching 90 °F.

Neither flower is remarkable, except both have perfume, very unusual for Camellias. (I am not computer literate so you would need to lookup pictures on the net .)

Are Camellias blooming anywhere else yet?  Most of the time I am hoping a January or February freeze does not kill the *C. japonica* buds before they open.

Answer (score 2):

No surprise that Camellia sasanqua is blooming now; depending on the particular cultivar,its bloom time in the northern hemisphere can be from fall through to winter, others a few in fall, more in late winter.

Camellia japonica, though occasionally showing one or two flowers in Fall, is a spring flowering one. But with climate change, and having had a cooler than usual September which warmed up towards the end of the month, I can testify to the fact that there is one here in West London,UK, round the  corner from me, in full flower at the moment, must have about 40 blooms. Probably won't be any left for spring, unfortunately.

Also apple blossom appearing on some trees now...